# Eclipse CDT and CMake + Ninja -- proper project organization

Tags: cmake, eclipse-cdt, ninja

I have a static library libXY and a program exeA using it. I fail to find a proper project setup which allows me to use *ninja* from within Eclipse CDT to build only what is needed to build.

So far, I had **one project** with ninja build files created by *cmake* which defined several targets which was perfect for building from command line:

- build everything if anything changed (aka `ninja all`)
- build libXY if any source files changed (aka `ninja libXY`)
- build libXY if any source files changed and build exeA if any source file changed and link (aka `ninja exeA`)

I imported the project (created with cmake's Eclipse CDT / Ninja generator) into Eclipse CDT, but there, I could only build *everything* (`ninja all`). I was unable to get *Ctrl-B* to build just the library and the proper target, I was unable to define targets within Eclipse.

As plan B, I created a setup where libXY and exeA are independent projects. I am unable to define the dependency from exeA to libXY so that the library is built automatically if any of its source files changed.

Help! What is the proper project architecture?